# webservice run automatically

Tags: asp.net

Is there any trick to run a Webservice automatically to check some date specific and performs some operations on particular date. Like sending birthday emails and so on?

Comment: Yes, in the Linux world for example there are cron jobs. What kind of platform are you on?

Comment: sir i am using a shared server, so i don't have server rights to change .

Answer (score 0):

That's what something like [Quartz.NET](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/) is for if you're writing .NET web services.

Comment: nopes sir , am working on asp.net. c# and i want to calculate some date specific activities, so i want it.

Comment: I don't think that's what a web service is for.  Those are usually triggered by synchronous HTTP requests.  A scheduled job is something different.

Comment: no, HTTP request is not a solution , let me clear more. i am developing a application in which there are so many user and we have DOB of every user and now we want that on every day the system checks the date and compare them from DOB , if the day of date is same then some activities performs automatically , because we don't wanna that a administrator run a particular form which perform all these stuffs

Comment: please tell me some solution.

Comment: @Abhisheks.net - we agree then.  Your solution is not about web services, it's about running a job automatically.  Your solution is a cron job, running under the control of the operating system on a server.  The cron job starts at the same time every day, accesses the database to get all user birth dates, and loops through the list to perform the automatic tasks for each one.  I'd recommend that you write the logic to do that, test it, and then worry about the scheduling once it's working.

Comment: oksss , fine can you provide me some example of that, and it will be worked on a shared server because we don't have all rights on the server

Comment: You should talk to the person who does have the rights to help you set such a thing up.  And no, I'm not providing you an example of how to write a script and set it up as a cron job.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a Windows Service.
In Windows Service you have to call the web service method when it's required.

Detailed Explanation:

1. Create a Webservice and implement the method to send the Birthday and Notification mails.
2. Create a Windows Service, Windows Service should check the current date and Birthday date,
   if it's equal (one day, two day before - according to configuration) - Invoke the web method.